# Video buffering in IE/Edge using Media Source Extensions

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, media-source

We are trying to use MSE (Media Source Extensions) to show real time video on a website. We are sending frames over websocket and trying our hardest to keep latency down.
Our current prototype is streaming very well in IE, Edge, Chrome, Safari etc. 
The issue we have is that IE and Edge insists on buffering around 3-5 seconds before starting to play the video. This is not acceptable in our use case (live video from security cameras).
We are wondering if there is some property or similar (we have tried setting preload=none, with no success) which removes this buffering?
All other browsers happily starts playing when the first frame is added to the sourceBuffer, and we want the same behavior from IE/Edge.
Is there any other workaround you can suggest for us?

The frames are in the [ISO BMFF format](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html)

Here is a [reproducing example](https://oskbor.github.io/ie_5s_buffer.html) I have created that measures the time from the first frame is appended to the video starts playing.It uses an interval to spoof data arriving over a websocket.

Results:

```
Browser       Delay(ms)
-----------------------
Chrome:           ~300
Safari @ Mac:       ~7
Chrome @ Android:  ~30
IE11 @ Win10:    ~3200
Edge:            ~3200
```

[Here](https://oskbor.github.io/ie_5s.mp4) is the mp4 file, if you want to examine it.

Comment: example link is 404

Comment: @totaam I have moved the files from google drive to github and updated the links. It should be working now again

Answer (score 10):

When you serve the video to IE or to Edge, use the following Javascript. It worked for me. [Here it is in GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/mvp-mse) as a simplified version of [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On my computer, the video plays almost instantly.

- Download GPAC installers [here](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/).
- Run it and install mp4box.
- Run `mp4box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap path\to\ie_5s.mp4`

You will now have a bunch of files alongside your original `.mp4`.

```
ie_5s.mp4
ie_5s_dash.mpd
ie_5s_dashinit.mp4
out_ie_5s.mp4
```

Rename the `.mpd` file to a `.xml` file.

Then create a new `.html` file is the same directory. Paste the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Media streaming example
  Reads an .mpd file created using mp4box and plays the file
-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Media streaming example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="filename" value="ie_5s_dash.xml" />
    <button id="load">Play</button>
    <br />
    <video id="myVideo" autoplay="autoplay">No video available</video>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also create a new `.js` file in the same directory.

```
/*globals window, console, XMLHttpRequest, document, Uint8Array, DOMParser, URL*/

(function () { /* code */

    'use strict';

    // Global Parameters from .mpd file
    var file;  // MP4 file
    var width;  //  Native width and height
    var height;

    // Elements
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    var playButton = document.getElementById("load");
    videoElement.poster = "poster.png";

    // Description of initialization segment, and approx segment lengths
    var initialization;

    // Video parameters
    var bandwidth; // bitrate of video

    // Parameters to drive segment loop
    var index = 0; // Segment to get
    var segments;

    // Source and buffers
    var mediaSource;
    var videoSource;

    // Parameters to drive fetch loop
    var segCheck;
    var lastTime = 0;
    var bufferUpdated = false;

    // Flags to keep things going
    var lastMpd = "";
    var requestId = 0;

    //  Logs messages to the console
    function log(s) {
        //  send to console
        //    you can also substitute UI here
        console.log(s);
    }

    //  Clears the log
    function clearLog() {
        console.clear();
    }

    function timeToDownload(range) {
        var vidDur = range.split("-");
        // Time = size * 8 / bitrate
        return (((vidDur[1] - vidDur[0]) * 8) / bandwidth);
    }

    //  Play segment plays a byte range (format nnnn-nnnnn) of a media file
    function playSegment(range, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (range || url) { // Make sure we've got incoming params
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + range);
            xhr.send();
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            try {
                xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) { //wait for video to load
                        //  Calculate when to get next segment based on time of current one
                        segCheck = (timeToDownload(range) * 0.8).toFixed(3); // Use point eight as fudge factor
                        // Add received content to the buffer
                        try {
                            videoSource.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
                        } catch (e) {
                            log('Exception while appending', e);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            } catch (e) {
                log(e);
                return; // No value for range
            }
        }
    }

    //  Get video segments
    function fileChecks() {
        // If we're ok on the buffer, then continue
        if (bufferUpdated === true) {
            if (index < segments.length) {
                // Loads next segment when time is close to the end of the last loaded segment
                if ((videoElement.currentTime - lastTime) >= segCheck) {
                    playSegment(segments[index].getAttribute("mediaRange").toString(), file);
                    lastTime = videoElement.currentTime;
                    index++;
                }
            } else {
                videoElement.removeEventListener("timeupdate", fileChecks, false);
            }
        }
    }

    //  Play our file segments
    function getStarted(url) {

        //  Start by loading the first segment of media
        playSegment(segments[index].getAttribute("mediaRange").toString(), url);

        // Display current index
        index++;

        //  Continue in a loop where approximately every x seconds reload the buffer
        videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", fileChecks, false);

    }

    function updateFunct() {
        //  This is a one shot function, when init segment finishes loading,
        //    update the buffer flag, call getStarted, and then remove this event.
        bufferUpdated = true;
        getStarted(file); // Get video playback started
        //  Now that video has started, remove the event listener
        videoSource.removeEventListener("update", updateFunct);
    }

    //  Load video's initialization segment
    function initVideo(range, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (range || url) { // make sure we've got incoming params

            // Set the desired range of bytes we want from the mp4 video file
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + range);
            segCheck = (timeToDownload(range) * 0.8).toFixed(3); // use point eight as fudge factor
            xhr.send();
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            try {
                xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) { // wait for video to load
                        // Add response to buffer
                        try {
                            videoSource.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
                            // Wait for the update complete event before continuing
                            videoSource.addEventListener("update", updateFunct, false);

                        } catch (e) {
                            log('Exception while appending initialization content', e);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            } catch (e) {
                log(e);
            }
        } else {
            return; // No value for range or url
        }
    }

    // Create mediaSource and initialize video
    function setupVideo() {
        clearLog(); // Clear console log

        //  Create the media source
        if (window.MediaSource) {
            mediaSource = new window.MediaSource();
        } else {
            log("mediasource or syntax not supported");
            return;
        }
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        videoElement.pause();
        videoElement.src = url;
        videoElement.width = width;
        videoElement.height = height;

        // Wait for event that tells us that our media source object is
        //   ready for a buffer to be added.
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
            try {
                videoSource = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4');
                initVideo(initialization, file);
            } catch (ex) {
                log('Exception calling addSourceBuffer for video', ex);
                return;
            }
        }, false);

        // Handler to switch button text to Play
        videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function () {
            playButton.innerText = "Play";
        }, false);

        // Handler to switch button text to pause
        videoElement.addEventListener("playing", function () {
            playButton.innerText = "Pause";
        }, false);
    }

    // Retrieve parameters from our stored .mpd file
    function getFileType(data) {
        try {
            file = data.querySelectorAll("BaseURL")[0].textContent.toString();
            var rep = data.querySelectorAll("Representation");
            width = rep[0].getAttribute("width");
            height = rep[0].getAttribute("height");
            bandwidth = rep[0].getAttribute("bandwidth");

            var ini = data.querySelectorAll("Initialization");
            initialization = ini[0].getAttribute("range");
            segments = data.querySelectorAll("SegmentURL");

        } catch (er) {
            log(er);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Gets the mpd file and parses it
    function getData(url) {
        if (url !== "") {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Set up xhr request
            xhr.open("GET", url, true); // Open the request
            xhr.responseType = "text"; // Set the type of response expected
            xhr.send();

            //  Asynchronously wait for the data to return
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                    var tempoutput = xhr.response;
                    var parser = new DOMParser(); //  Create a parser object

                    // Create an xml document from the .mpd file for searching
                    var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(tempoutput, "text/xml", 0);
                    log("parsing mpd file");

                    // Get and display the parameters of the .mpd file
                    getFileType(xmlData);

                    // Set up video object, buffers, etc
                    setupVideo();
                }
            };

            // Report errors if they happen during xhr
            xhr.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
                log("Error: " + e + " Could not load url.");
            }, false);
        }
    }

    // Click event handler for load button
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //  If video is paused then check for file change
        if (videoElement.paused === true) {
            // Retrieve mpd file, and set up video
            var curMpd = document.getElementById("filename").value;
            //  If current mpd file is different then last mpd file, load it.
            if (curMpd !== lastMpd) {
                //  Cancel display of current video position
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
                lastMpd = curMpd;
                getData(curMpd);
            } else {
                //  No change, just play
                videoElement.play();
            }
        } else {
            //  Video was playing, now pause it
            videoElement.pause();
        }
    }, false);

    // Do a little trickery, start video when you click the video element
    videoElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
        playButton.click();
    }, false);

    // Event handler for the video element errors
    document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        log("video error: " + e.message);
    }, false);

}());
```

When I serve the `index.html` file from a Web server to Edge or IE 11+ the video displays instantly. Time permitting and if you are interested, I will host the demo live for you to see.

Comment: Hi, Ive just looked through your example but wont have time to set it up today. Since all segments are on the server already, isn't the reason that the video starts playing simply that IE/Edge quickly can buffer enough to start playing? Im having a hard time following what is going on so I might be wrong :) In my case the frames are coming over the websocket in real time so there is no future segments to fetch from the server.

Comment: "...isn't the reason that the video starts playing simply that IE/Edge quickly can buffer enough to start playing?" You may well be right. Hmm. I do not understand it very well either. :)

Comment: "...In my case the frames are coming over the websocket in real time..." It would be great to have an example of that to test. Could you post more details about how to reproduce your setup. The [reproducing example](https://ea7e83c432c066554d3ef3e6580aa1af9bd594a1.googledrive.com/host/0BwqnHXhKkJ7mfjF5clFzSUFSY3pjSzhxZlA0TnpIeEo2bHlaY2FZd3RhWDFHY1o2eXZsYXc/ie_5s_buffer.html) that you posted is not working for me on any browser. I think what you're saying is that we need to use a live video feed instead of an mp4. Out of curiosity, why did you post the mp4 in the first place?

Comment: hmm, strange that the example isnt working for you. I will double check that it still works for me. The mp4 i posted is a recording of the websocket traffic, in the example it is chunked up and fed to the sourcebuffer in a setInterval function.

Comment: Try waiting a few seconds before pushing play, that might be the reason it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Done. :) In Edge, I waited 15-20 seconds, and then the video rendered on hitting play. It does not play at all in Firefox. Is that by design?

Comment: Firefox nightly build might work, their MES + h264 support is very flaky and under current development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88804/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-oskbor).

Answer (score 9):

IE buffering is done by looking at the sample duration in the MP4 TRUN box. You could perhaps solve it by adding ~5 seconds of fake data and then remove that once the video starts playing.

Comment: That might work, but  feels like a very hacky solution. Great idea though!

Comment: Do you have a reference link?

Comment: The sample duration is set in the TRUN box: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469478.aspx

Comment: Haven't been able to implement this, the element starts playing when I append the fake fragment but stops again when the fragment is removed. Could be a timing issue, but doesn't seem to be working at the moment.